# R json obects with a single parameter value

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I want to create the following json string

```
{"water": {"amount": 0}}
```

To do that I wrote the following code:

```
  df_water <- list(amount = 0)

  info <- list(water = df_water) %>%
  toJSON()
```

But that results to:

```
{"water": {"amount": [0]}}
```

Any clues how can I remove the array from "amount" value?

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto_unbox = TRUE` - by default it is `FALSE`

```
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)
list(water= df_water) %>% 
   toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

-output

```
{"water":{"amount":0}}
```